# Background color of checkbox and selection in css

Tags: html, css

I want to change background color of my check-box and i can't

here is my code :

```
<input type="checkbox" class="color"/>
```

and css

```
.color{

    backgoround-color:red;
}
```

Where is my error :/
 And also i want to change the selection style
    
        Terminal

I tried like below:

```
<select class="cls">
        <option>Terminal</option>
    </select>
<div class="cls">
<select>
        <option>Terminal</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with the above typos fixed I don't think checkbox can accept a background-color (doesn't work in chrome for me right now).

You will have to use a custom checkbox image to set a background color on one. I have used this technique successfully before: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/ .

Answer (score 2):

There is a spelling error in the property name:

```
background-color:red; /* Instead of backgoround-color:red; */
```

There is also another spelling error on the select tag:

```
<select class="cls"> <!-- Instead of <select calss="cls"> -->
```

Comment: and its `color` not `cls`

Comment: @AlexK. I just left that one on there.  `color` is so different from `cls` I assumed the OP was talking about another class they had not shown.

Comment: Thank you.. I don't have that error in code.. I'am little crazy now so i fast typed that...

Answer (score 2):

You wrote "background" wrong. It should work when you correct it to

```
.color{
    background-color:red;
}
```